# Запятая в сочетании "всё что"

Tags: пунктуация

Всё что я запомнил — это труба и тромбон.

Требуется ли запятая после "всё"?

Answer (score 5):

Да, запятая нужна. Здесь нет неразложимого сочетания вроде "всё что угодно".
"Что я запомнил" — придаточное предложение внутри главного: "Всё — это труба и тромбон". Следовательно, запятую нужно поставить и после "запомнил":

*Всё, что я запомнил, — это труба и тромбон.*

Answer (score 3):

*Требуется ли запятая после "всё"?*
Да, конечно, запятая требуется — начинается придаточное предложение "что я запомнил".
Но нужна и еще одна запятая — та, которая закрывает это придаточное. Таким образом, перед "это" должны быть и запятая, и тире (каждый из этих знаков препинания ставится на собственном основании).

**Всё, что я запомнил, — это труба и тромбон.**

*Я понял: все, что от меня требуется, — это пообещать ей маленькую прибавку* (Г. Миллер).

*Собственно, я уже пытался, но всё, что мне удалось увидеть, — это подземная река* (Э. Ан).

*Всё, что я хотел, — это сделать Колумбию лучше* (П. Эскобар).